# CSS makes div unequal in firefox and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, web

I've made two divs for navigation with given css:
for first button:

```
.OptionsButton .DropDownButtonOverlay
{
    margin: 0px -95px 0px 0px;
    width: 92px;
    height: 38.5px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 2;
}



.tenPxLeft
{
    margin-left: 10px;    
}

.floatRight
{
    float: right;
}

.regularButton
{
    background-color: #008BE1; 
    border: none;
}

.optionsButton
{
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

and the second button is as this:

```
.defaultButton
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Segoe UI, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    padding: 10px 15px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* fixes chrome bug */
}

.tenPxLeft
{
    margin-left: 10px;    
}

.floatRight
{
    float: right;
}

.regularButton
{
    background-color: #008BE1; 
    border: none;
}
```

the problem I am dealing with is they look fine on Chrome and IE (alligned nicely). However when I go to firefox they don't get alligned as well as intended (i am putting them in another div as a top menu thingy).

It seems like the font is influencing that. I've tried making font by percentage (100.01%), however it makes it look nice in firefox, but then ruins the view in IE and Chrome. 
how could I fix this?

Comment: Please, make a fiddle or a snippet to view the problem

Comment: update code with html in jsfiddle or code editor

Comment: Without the HTML, you are showing us your crayons but not the coloring book.

Comment: You don't have quotes around "Segoe UI" and sans-serif should be lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that firefox tends to work differently on divs (I knew this before, but the solution was unclear), therefore I added Max-Height attribute on the button that expands due to text-size in it's body which fixed the problem.

Comment: Firefox does NOT handle divs differently. Look elsewhere for the solution.

Comment: well, some pages do show differently, might not be div problem, but css is what I probably wanted to say. Either way max-height solved the problem and the page is represented correctly now in all the browsers as far as I can tell.